# The use of " to access"

Tags: word-usage

Is using "access" as a verb in different contexts accepted in standard English ?

[Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/access)' definition as a verb shows limited use, such as in the realm of computer technology or the Internet. However, apart from this, people use it in different contexts as in the following passage.

For example:

> Research shows that tobacco prevention programs must conduct a
>   comprehensive set of strategies to be effective The Tobacco and Vapor
>   Program provides services to help people quit, conducts public
>   awareness and media campaigns, supports local programs in communities
>   and schools, supports enforcement of policies to keep kids from
>   **accessing** tobacco products, and evaluates the effectiveness of program
>   activities.

http://www.doh.wa.gov/DataandStatisticalReports/HealthBehaviors/Tobacco/FactSheets/Compliance

Comment: Yes, it is. The semantic range stretches from *availability* to *acquisition*.

Comment: @Lawrence Can we say dictionaries could not catch up with the use of it yet because its verb form is derived from noun form, which is used more commonly.

Comment: "Definition of access:
transitive verb
:  to get at :  to gain access to: (such as)
:  to be able to use, enter, or get near (something)." (Merriam-Webster) See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/access

Comment: @Mrt I'm not sure that's the case. I realised that my examples used *access* as a noun, so I'm deleting my answer for now while I look for better examples.

Comment: [Collins and KHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/access) list the non-computer-related verbal usages before the computer-related ones.

Comment: Mrt, I think it's the other way around. "To access" has been used much longer than computers have been around; I think online dictionaries are using computing examples these days just to appear more "relevant." See Edwin's comment, above.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard I think they're using them because they're by far the most common. [This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+access&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20access%3B%2Cc0) shows that 'to access' has indeed been around for ages, but that it only became common after the 1960s. I suspect that AHD (op cit) reflects usage better than Collins and Webster's, and that the latter give the more general rather than the more common usage first. Though doubtless the more general usage has become more common alongside this.

Comment: @Mrt There's some good information in the comments. I've placed a couple of examples in my answer and undeleted it, but it would be useful for you to collate the information from the comments into your own answer.

Comment: Edwin, I just noticed that as well. I wish the Ngram showed what the small "blip" of use was around 1697. Such a steep rise since 1950 suggests it may be more technology-related than I realized.

Comment: @MarkHubbard It may be the other way around but I heard before that there is tendency that some nouns are used as a verb. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *access* is used as a verb in standard English, including contexts other than computing. Here are a couple of examples involving food:

- St Vincent de Paul Canberra/Goulburn Conferences can provide support with accessing food.
  [- St Vincent de Paul Society](https://www.vinnies.org.au/findhelp/view/95)
- This needs assessment aims to collect information on the barriers to accessing food programs, the opportunities for improving food access, the barriers to eating fresh vegetables and fruit, and the opportunities to increasing their consumption among food-insecure people in Cobourg, Ontario.
  [- Tsang, Holt, Azevedo in NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21733349)

Comment: And "access the curriculum" is possibly a strong collocation.